# Deployment Descriptor in web apps

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, web-deployment, fedora

I am in a habit of working on Windows; this is the first time I am using Tomcat on Linux. When I deploy my web app, Tomcat is not able to access the welcome file listed in web.xml. But when I try accessing it through the URL, then I am able to. Also, no servlets are able to run because Tomcat doesn't seem to read web.xml. My directory structure and all are entirely correct.

The directory structure of the app is

```
                HelloWorld
                         |
                         |-form.html
                         |-WEB-INF
                                 |
                                 |-classes
                                 |-web.xml
```

Can anybody see the reason why web.xml cannot be accessed?

Comment: Hard to tell - is web.xml under /WEB-INF in your deployment?  Did you create a WAR file?

Comment: yes it is under WEB-INF,I did not create a war file,I also tried disabling the other web.xml of tomcat in conf/contents.xml but still, it had no effect....I searched online a lot but still cant find a solution. Is there some default setting in tomcat for web.xml that I need to turn on or off??

Comment: Create a proper WAR file and deploy it under Tomcat /web apps folder. That's the right way to do it.  There is no other web.xml that matters here. You need to isolate your app from the app server.